# What does it mean for a propagator in position space to have $p=0$ in momentum space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, propagator

In $d=4$ dimensions, the Fourier transform of a propagator from position space to momentum space is:

$$\frac{1}{x^2} = \int d^4p \frac{e^{-ip\cdot x}}{p^2} \tag{1}$$

In the case of $p=0$ in momentum space, what does it mean for the propagator in position space? How would $x$ look like?

Naively, I set $p=0$ in the RHS of $(1)$ and it looks like that $x=0$ should be the answer. However I don't think that this is the right way to proceed. Any idea?

EDIT:

To give some context, here is the identity mentioned in the comments which I am trying to prove:

$$\delta\left(\sum p_k\right)\left\lbrace \frac{1}{(p_1+p_2)^2}\left(\partial_{p_1} - \partial_{p_2}\right)^2\left(\partial_{p_3} - \partial_{p_4}\right)^2 \frac{(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_3-p_4)}{p_1^2p_2^2p_3^2p_4^2} + \frac{1}{(p_1+p_3)^2}\left(\partial_{p_1} - \partial_{p_3}\right)^2\left(\partial_{p_2} - \partial_{p_4}\right)^2 \frac{(p_1+p_3)^2 - \sum p_k^2}{p_1^2p_2^2p_3^2p_4^2} - \frac{1}{(p_1+p_4)^2}\left(\partial_{p_1} - \partial_{p_4}\right)^2\left(\partial_{p_2} - \partial_{p_3}\right)^2 \frac{(p_1+p_4)^2 - \sum p_k^2}{p_1^2p_2^2p_3^2p_4^2}\right\rbrace \overset{!}{=}0 \tag{2}$$

where all the sums are for $k=1,...,4$. In position space, this identity relates the so-called slashed-box integral with derivatives and the box integral together (see eq. A.7 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208178)). Now I am interested in the terms with a $\partial_{p_i}^2\partial_{p_j}\cdot\partial_{p_k}$. For example in the first big term, after using the product rule, I have such a term:

$$\delta\left(\sum p_k\right)\frac{1}{(p_1+p_2)^2}\partial_{p_1}^2 \frac{1}{p_1^2}\partial_{p_3}\cdot\partial_{p_4} \frac{(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_3-p_4)}{p_2^2p_3^2p_4^2} = -(2\pi)^2 \delta(p_2+p_3+p_4)\delta(p_1) \partial_{p_3}\cdot\partial_{p_4} \frac{-p_2\cdot(p_3-p_4)}{p_2^4p_3^2p_4^2} \tag{3}$$

It does not seem to cancel with the other terms, so I would like to see how it looks like in position space. I cannot transform it back to position space (there remains some integrals). So maybe if I know what this $\delta(p_1)$ means in position space, I could look at the original expression in position space and take the appropriate limit.

Comment: $p$ is a dummy variable which is being integrated over on the RHS, so it doesn't make sense to set it to zero.  I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.  The position space propagator sums over all possible momenta of the intermediate particle, $p=0$ being one of them.

Comment: @J.Murray Right, I am also not sure how to formulate the question. Basically I want to prove an identity in position space, in which the LHS is fully known in momentum space as well, and is equal to the right-hand side up to a term with a $\delta(p)$ inside. I thought that if I could understand what $p=0$ is in position space, I could study that limiting case in position space directly. Sorry if this is unclear, it is not an easy question to formulate, and the identity is so complicated that I don't believe that it would help to include it in the post.

Comment: I suspect that including the identity would provide valuable context.

Comment: @J.Murray Done. Thinking about it, I think that a term with $\delta(p)$ in position space corresponds to a term without $x$ in position space, since Fourier transforming $1$ gives $\delta(p)$: $\int d^4 x\ 1 \cdot e^{-i p\cdot x} = \delta(p)$. Does that make sense?